# Como mudar um valor específico de uma string em uma array?

Tags: javascript, array, string

Eu tenho uma array:

```
let arr = ['Feijao, Arroz', 'Melancia', 'Banana', 'Laranja,Uva']
```

e gostaria que ela se tornasse:

```
let arr = ['Feijao, Arroz', 'Melancia', 'Banana', 'Laranja, Uva']//(consertando o erro de vírgula).
```

Escrevi o código

```
let arr = ['Feijao, Arroz', 'Melancia', 'Banana', 'Laranja,Uva']
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let search = arr[i].search(/,\w/g)
    if(search >= 0){
        arr[i][search] += ' '
    }
    console.log(search);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Porém o mesmo não muda absolutamente nada. Já tentei usar charAt, mas não consigo formular a lógica certa..

(os valores em conjunto dentro da string são propositais: ['A, B', 'C', 'D,E'])

Comment: Tem certeza que o exemplo que você deu é o resultado que você gostaria e não que fosse `['Feijao, Arroz', 'Melancia', 'Banana', 'Laranja', 'Uva']`?

Comment: Absoluta. Alguns valores seriam agrupados em uma única string: 'Feijão, Arroz' , 'Laranja, Uva'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta utilizar a substituição de uma expressão regular em conjunto com a função `map` do `Array`:

```js
let arr = ['Feijao, Arroz', 'Melancia', 'Banana', 'Laranja,Uva'];

arr = arr.map((item) => item.replace(/,([^ ]{1})/g, ', $1'));

console.log(arr);
```

---

Na expressão regular:

- Corresponde o caracter `,` literalmente;
- [Agrupamento de Captura](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) `([^ ]{1})`:

  - Corresponde apenas um caracter que não esteja presente na lista `[^ ]`;
  - Quantificador `{1}` - Corresponde exatamente uma vez a lista anterior;

Utilizamos a expressão regular para isolar o caracter que vem depois da vírgula para, posteriormente, substituir toda a expressão por `,`  + o que houver dentro do grupo.

---

> [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>
> O método map() invoca a função callback passada por argumento para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.
>
> ```
> var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
> var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
> // roots é [1, 2, 3], numbers ainda é [1, 4, 9]
> ```

---

> [**`Agrupamentos`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references)
>
> `(x)` -  Corresponde `x` e memoriza a correspondência. Esses são chamados parênteses de captura.
>
> Por exemplo, `/(foo)/` corresponde e memoriza "foo" em "foo bar". A substring correspondida pode ser chamada novamente dos elementos do array resultante `[1], ..., [n]` ou das propriedades predefinidas do objeto `RegExp` `$1, ..., $9`.

Comment: Gostei da solução, porém não entendi o segundo parâmetro da função replace(). Poderia me explicar para que/como funciona esse '$1'?

Comment: @ju4ncrls adicionei uma explicação mais detalhada sobre a expressão e agrupamentos de expressão regular